# Android Picasso does not load all image to imageview

Tags: java, android, list, imageview, picasso

I am trying to load images to imageview in my ListAdapter. However while I am passing 10 thumbnail images to listAdapter and set them in imageview, only 1 or none is visible in imageview. As I understand from docs, I dont need to use any asyntask, since picasso library has already working asyntask. Could you please help me how I can handle this issue?

// Calling CustumListAdapter like this;

```
CustomListAdapter customListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, resultArrayList);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_score);
listView.setAdapter(customListAdapter)
```

// And here is my CustomListAdapter class

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private ArrayList<String> resultContent;
    //private Integer[] imageid;
    private Activity context;


    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> resultContent) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_ident_result2, resultContent);
        this.context = context;
        this.resultContent = resultContent;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_ident_result2, null, true);

        if (position % 2 == 0) {

            TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textView_score);
            textViewName.setText(resultContent.get(position));

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView_score);
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(IdentResultActivity.splittedBitmaps.get(position + 1));

            Picasso.with(this.context).load(resultContent.get(position + 1)).into(imageView);

        }
        return  listViewItem;

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I used `.placeholder(R.drawble.progress)` and I can see one image placed without problem, rest are progress.png

**EDIT2:**

Here is my imageView xml file;

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView_score" />
```

Comment: But when you scroll the list, does it display the correct image?

Comment: all images are empty (sometimes it shows 1 image), wheter I scroll or not.

Comment: Did you check the JSON response? Also please check the size of your images.

Comment: May be it's because of bigger size of images you have in your *json*. So it will take time to load images using *Picasso*.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes I check all thumnails and there is no problem it works fine in browser. Here is an one of thumbnail that I want to place. https://static.findface.pro/5772824e2540183b69d7f7fd/767bf4df0c8a04361aaf5e6b74eb4d8c_thumb.jpg

Comment: @jaydroider please see my edit, when I use .error() 9 out of 10 images are with error.png

Comment: @jaydroider I am sorry, it is not showing error.png, it shows progressing. I mean only placeholder is working

Comment: give imageview a fixed width and height and then check

Comment: @peeyushpathak I already defined my imageView fixed. Please see my `edit2` is it what you mean?

Comment: what is the size of image?

Comment: @peeyushpathak I found the problem is about server side. `HTTP` request is directing to `HTTPS`, looks like `picasso` is not compatible about forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the parameters of `inflater.inflate` should be `(R.layout.activity_ident_result2, parent, false)`

Answer (score -1):

U need to create loop for adding every image to [] and then u need to show it. Becouse of ur posted code u adding just one image.